# How to add Cluster markers to Choropleth with Folium

Tags: python, folium

I've been working for a while with Choropleth and Cluster marker maps in Folium (which are great).  My question is whether it is possible to combine them in one map, which is so that I can see how much one variable affects another.  I can get both map types to work individually so no problems there.  This is my attempted code to combine the two so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import folium
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster

input_filename="input_filename.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(input_filename,encoding='utf8')
geo = 'blah.json'
comparison = 'comparison.csv'
comparison_data = pd.read_csv(comparison)

m = folium.Map(location=[Lat,Lon], zoom_start=12)

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=geo,
    name='choropleth',
    data=comparison_data,
    columns=['col1','col2'],
    key_on='feature.properties.ID',
    fill_color='OrRd',
    fill_opacity=0.5,
    line_opacity=0.5,
    legend_name='Blah (%)'
).add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
marker_cluster = MarkerCluster().add_to(m)

for row in df.itertuples():
    folium.Marker(location=[row.Lat,row.Lon],popup=row.Postcode).add_to(marker_cluster)

m
```

It produces the choropleth but won't layer the cluster markers as well.  Worth noting that I've had a problem with cluster markers separately where they wouldn't display in Jupyter notebook, but I got around it by saving the file as an html, which was then viewable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok so I've solved it, really pleased!!  The solution was to do the marker cluster first, and then follow-up with the Choropleth:

```
import pandas as pd
import folium
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster

m = folium.Map(location=[Lat,Lon], zoom_start=12)

input_filename="input_filename.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(input_filename,encoding='utf8')
geo = 'blah.json'
comparison = 'comparison.csv'
comparison_data = pd.read_csv(comparison)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
marker_cluster = MarkerCluster().add_to(m)

for row in df.itertuples():
    folium.Marker(location=[row.Lat,row.Lon],popup=row.Postcode).add_to(marker_cluster)

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=geo,
    name='choropleth',
    data=comparison_data,
    columns=['col1','col2'],
    key_on='feature.properties.ID',
    fill_color='OrRd',
    fill_opacity=0.5,
    line_opacity=0.5,
    legend_name='Blah (%)'
).add_to(m)

m
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from random import randint
import folium

def rgb_to_hex(rgb):
    return '#%02x%02x%02x' % rgb

mp = folium.Map(location=[40.6, -73.7], scale = 10)

colors = []
while len(colors) != 50:
    r = randint(0, 255)
    g = randint(0, 255)
    b = randint(0, 255)
    if rgb_to_hex((r, g, b)) not in colors:
        colors.append(rgb_to_hex((r, g, b)))
        
for j in range(df.shape[0]):
    lat = df.iloc[j]['latitude']
    lon = df.iloc[j]['longitude']
    color = colors[int(df.iloc[j]['clust'])]
    
    folium.Circle(location=[lat, lon], radius=8, color = color).add_to(mp)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).